# BouncyCastel Cast5 setkey

Tags: c#, openssl, bouncycastle, encryption

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;

namespace Common.Encryption {

    public class Cast5Cryptographer {
        private bool forEncryption;
        private BufferedBlockCipher cipher;

        public Cast5Cryptographer(bool forEncryption) {
            this.forEncryption = forEncryption;
            cipher = new BufferedBlockCipher(new CfbBlockCipher(new Cast5Engine(), 64));
            cipher.Init(forEncryption, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BC234xs45nme7HU9")), new byte[8]));
        }

        public void ReInit(byte[] IV, BigInteger pubkey) {
            cipher.Init(forEncryption, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(pubkey.ToByteArrayUnsigned()), IV));
        }

        public int BlockSize {
            get {
                return cipher.GetBlockSize();
            }
        }

        public byte[] DoFinal() {
            return cipher.DoFinal();
        }

        public byte[] DoFinal(byte[] buffer) {
            return cipher.DoFinal(buffer);
        }

        public byte[] DoFinal(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len) {
            return cipher.DoFinal(buffer, startIndex, len);
        }

        public byte[] ProcessBytes(byte[] buffer) {
            return cipher.ProcessBytes(buffer);
        }

        public byte[] ProcessBytes(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len) {
            return cipher.ProcessBytes(buffer, startIndex, len);
        }
    }
}
```

it's working fine with the key above which it's 16 length , but when am trying to `ReInit()` it with this key
`byte[] newkey = new byte[] { 0x39, 0x65, 0x38, 0x63, 0x64, 0x32, 0x36, 0x63, 0x37, 0x37, 0x34, 0x31, 0x33, 0x65, 0x61, 0x36, 0x65, 0x35, 0x35, 0x39, 0x61, 0x32, 0x35, 0x32, 0x66, 0x30, 0x31, 0x35, 0x32, 0x38, 0x66, 0x39, 0x34, 0x38, 0x66, 0x33, 0x33, 0x34, 0x32, 0x62, 0x31, 0x38, 0x37, 0x36, 0x34, 0x61, 0x66, 0x35, 0x36, 0x38, 0x62, 0x39, 0x63, 0x39, 0x30, 0x33, 0x63, 0x35, 0x38, 0x38, 0x35, 0x34, 0x65, 0x63 };`

it throw this exception `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

`for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++) {
                x[i] = (int)(key[i] & 0xff);
            }`

inside the `SetKey` method in `Cast5Engine.cs` , so I updated this method so instead of having fixed length to `x` which is 16 , I made it

`int[] x = new int[key.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) x[i] = 0;`

```
        /* copy the key into x */
        for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++) {
            x[i] = (int)(key[i] & 0xff);
        }`
```

but now by comparing the result which am getting from `Cast5` of `BouncyCastel` to the `Cast5` of `OpenSSL` , it seems like `Bouncycastel Cast5` is not being updated with the right key, so it produce wrong Encryption/Decryption.

is there any suggestion to fix the `Setkey` method?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source code for OpenSSL's CAST_setKey method...

```
    void CAST_set_key(CAST_KEY *key, int len, const unsigned char *data)
#ifdef OPENSSL_FIPS
    {
    fips_cipher_abort(CAST);
    private_CAST_set_key(key, len, data);
    }
void private_CAST_set_key(CAST_KEY *key, int len, const unsigned char *data)
#endif
    {
    CAST_LONG x[16];
    CAST_LONG z[16];
    CAST_LONG k[32];
    CAST_LONG X[4],Z[4];
    CAST_LONG l,*K;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<16; i++) x[i]=0;
    if (len > 16) len=16;
```

See the line "if (len > 16) len = 16;", they only keep the first 16 bytes of the key. This wouldn't happen to be for Conquer Online 2.0 would it?, I recognise "BC234xs45nme7HU9".

Comment: yeah , and I figured that out long time ago :P